# Aligning specific widgets within a form within separate rows flutter

Tags: flutter

I am building a counter form. The form has a column and each column contains a row with a checkbox, text, + and - buttons and a text field.

The problem I have is that based on the length of text (gray rectangles in the picture)that I have the elements move around and dont look horizontally aligned.

I was wondering what is the best practice to align elements between rows (specifically the + and - buttons along with the text)?

[image]

Here's the code for my row:

```
Row(
  children: [
    Checkbox(value: CheckboxValue[fieldName],
      onChanged: (bool value) {
        setState(() {
          CheckboxValue[fieldName] = value;
          print('debug : changed $fieldName checkbox value');
          if (value == true && FieldValues[fieldName] <= 0) {
            TextControllers[fieldName].text = '1';
          }
        });
      }
    ),
    Text(fieldName),
    SizedBox(width: 20),
    IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.remove_circle_outline),
      onPressed: generateAdderFunction(fieldName, -1),
    ),
    ConstrainedBox(
      constraints: BoxConstraints.tight(Size(30, 25)),
      child: TextFormField(
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        inputFormatters: < TextInputFormatter > [
          FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r '[0-9]')),
        ],
        controller: TextControllers[fieldName],
        onSaved: (String value) {
          print('debug : Value for field  saved as "$value"');
        },
      )
    ),
    IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle_outline),
      onPressed: generateAdderFunction(fieldName, 1),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Any tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the easiest change would be to change:
`Text(fieldName)` to `Expanded(child: Text(fieldName))`

Comment: Thanks! this and a bit of fontsize management worked perfectly